# Pull values in a variable from another variable

Tags: linux, bash, variables, cut

I am trying to pull a value from a sequence, based on the entry of the parameter in the file. In my case, the values are going to be either "seq", "date", or "count".

```
function ParseHeader {
    local varHeaderLine=$1
    local varType=$2
    local varOut=""
    
    if [[ -z "$varType" ]]; then
        echo "Cannot find! - ($varType)"
        exit 1
        
    elif [[ "$varType" = "seq" ]]; then
        varOut=$(echo "$varHeaderLine" | cut -d\| -f 3)
        echo "Sequence: $varOut"
    elif [[ "$varType" = "date" ]]; then
        varOut=$(echo "$varHeaderLine" | cut -d\| -f 4)
        echo "Date: $varOut"
    elif [[ "$varType" = "count" ]]; then
        varOut=$(echo "$varHeaderLine" | cut -d\| -f 5)
        echo "Line Count: $varOut"
    else
        echo "Invalid input! Your Header is: $varHeaderLine"
    fi
        return $?
}

sequence='XXXXX|Y|1|20220429|9999'

ProfSeq=$(ParseHeader "${sequence}" "count")


echo $ProfSeq
```

This is a piece out of the whole file, but what is happening here is that I am going to receive a file, pull its sequence, and then pull some value from that particular sequence.
Thanks for the help, this is what I ended up with. Now I'm looking for it to be less CPU intensive, if possible.

Note: This piece is out of a while file script that will be running daily for different servers in different environments

Comment: I still don't understand fully when and where to use single bracket '[' and when to use double bracket '[[' in bash. And also when to add quotations to variables and when to have them in curly brackets.

Comment: What is your problem, exactly? What is the behavior of the code you show and what is wrong with it? Please answer by editing your question, not in comment.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet Made some changes. I hope that gives a better explanation.

Comment: If you are writing your script specifically for `bash`, then you can, and probably should, use only `[[`, never `[`.  If you want broader compatibility among shells from the Bourne family, however, then the reverse (or alternatively in that case, use `test` instead of `[`).

Comment: @JohnBollinger Correct! This is strictly for bash. It used to be with double brackets, but I was just messing around to see if it makes any difference. Thanks for the note!

Comment: Your function seems to work for me as I think you expect.  Is the problem you see perhaps because your function call uses the value of `$sequence` before any value is assigned to that variable?

Comment: @JohnBollinger YESSSS! Simple mistakes...what can I say! Thank you so much, this was getting me so frustrated for quite some time. It works now

Comment: Also, it is relatively expensive to launch processes, so if good performance for large inputs is an objective, then minimizing use of external tools such as `cut` is relatively important.  `bash` can do quite a lot internally, without such aids.

Comment: well my more-experienced co-worker told me about using 'cut' and that is why I went with it. CPU usage is the concern, as this file will be running daily on the server for multiple large files. Is there any other way to make things less CPU intensive? I would also like to point out, that this script file will be used for multiple servers across multiple environments. If that makes a difference to what you might be suggesting.

Comment: Performance is best evaluated in a more holistic way.  Improving individual functions is fine (and for this function, I would leverage `read`, which is a builtin for `bash`, to split the sequence into an array), but you also need to ask whether yours is the right function at all.  For example, if you're going to want more than one of the parts from each sequence, then obtaining each one via a separate function call is inefficient if you can get all of them from one function call with roughly the same cost.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Understood! Thank you so much for the guidance and help! Much appreciated

Comment: @markp-fuso sorry about that! Change has been made for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Focusing solely on the current piece of code ...

Assumptions/Understandings:

- the variable `ProfSeq` is to contain the output from the function's `echo` calls; we can eliminate the subprocess call (`ProfSeq=$( ... subprocess call ...)`) by having the function replace the `echo "..."` calls with `ProfSeq="..."` (ie, have the function directly populate the `ProfSeq` variable
- additional performance improvements can be derived from eliminating the double subprocess calls to split `varHeaderLine` (`$(echo ... | cut ...)`) with the `bash/read` builtin

One idea for a function rewrite:

```
ParseCOTHeader () {

local varHeaderLine=$1
local -l varType=$2                                # force to all lowercase
local ignore1 ignore2 in_seq in_date in_count rc

# split varHeaderLine into 5 variables based on '|' delimiter:
# NOTE: assumes varHeaderLine has exactly 5x '|' delimited fields otherwise OP
#       may want to add some code to validate the structure of varHeaderLine

IFS='|' read -r ignore1 ignore2 in_seq in_date in_count <<< "${varHeaderLine}"

# reset variables:

ProfSeq=
rc=0

if [[ -z "${varType}" ]]
then
    ProfSeq="Cannot find! - ($2)"                  # since varType=$2 is empty at this point we will always print '()' ... ?
    rc=1
else
    case "${varType}" in
         seq)    ProfSeq="Sequence: ${in_seq}" ;;
         date)   ProfSeq="Date: ${in_date}" ;;
         count)  ProfSeq="Line Count: ${in_count}" ;;
         *)      ProfSeq="Invalid input! Your Header is: '$varHeaderLine'"
                 rc=1 ;;
    esac
fi

return "${rc}"
}
```

Putting the function through its paces:

```
$ sequence='SWHHR|H|1|20220429|9999'

$ ParseCOTHeader "${sequence}" 'seq'
$ echo "$? : ${ProfSeq}"
0 : Sequence: 1

$ ParseCOTHeader "${sequence}" 'DaTe'
$ echo "$? : ${ProfSeq}"
0 : Date: 20220429

$ ParseCOTHeader "${sequence}" 'COUNT'
$ echo "$? : ${ProfSeq}"
0 : Line Count: 9999

$ ParseCOTHeader "${sequence}" 'fire-truck'
$ echo "$? : ${ProfSeq}"
1 : Invalid input! Your Header is: 'SWHHR|H|1|20220429|9999'

$ ParseCOTHeader "${sequence}" ''
$ echo "$? : ${ProfSeq}"
1 : Cannot find! - ()
```

---

If repeated calls to the function need to save the message string in different variables:

- add the line `local -n myoutput=$3` in the top section of the function (this defines a local nameref variable `myoutput` to act as a pointer to the variable name passed in $3)
- replace all `ProfSeq="..."` with `myoutput="..."` in the function
- remove the line `ProfSeq=` (variable reset) in the function

Taking the new function for a test spin:

```
$ sequence='SWHHR|H|1|20220429|9999'

$ ParseCOTHeader "${sequence}" 'seq' ProfSeq
$ echo "$? : ${ProfSeq}"
0 : Sequence: 1

$ ParseCOTHeader "${sequence}" 'DaTe' ProfSeq
$ echo "$? : ${ProfSeq}"
0 : Date: 20220429

$ ParseCOTHeader "${sequence}" 'COUNT' ProfSeq
$ echo "$? : ${ProfSeq}"
0 : Line Count: 9999

$ ParseCOTHeader "${sequence}" 'fire-truck' SomeOtherVar
$ echo "$? : ${SomeOtherVar}"
1 : Invalid input! Your Header is: 'SWHHR|H|1|20220429|9999'

$ ParseCOTHeader "${sequence}" '' YetAnotherVar
$ echo "$? : ${YetAnotherVar}"
1 : Cannot find! - ()
```

Comment: This looks awesome! Thank you for your clean outputs of what the results can be. I am still new to Linux, what is exactly '<<<' for? Also, is it totally fine to leave "Profseq=" blank to reset the variables? I am using this in bash.

Comment: `read` typically reads input from a file; the `<<<` is called a 'here-string' and allows us to feed a string (eg, the contents of `"${varHeaderLine}"`) to `read` in such a way that it looks like a 'file' to `read`; yes, `ProfSeq=` should also work as will `unset ProfSeq`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `read` and associative arrays:

```sh
$ function ParseHeader {
  local -A fields=(["seq"]=2 ["date"]=3 ["count"]=4)
  local -A mess=(["seq"]="Sequence" ["date"]="Date" ["count"]="Line Count")

  IFS='|' read -ra arr <<< "$1"
  if [[ -n "${fields[$2]:+x}" ]]; then
    printf -v ProfSeq '%s: %s' "${mess[$2]}" "${arr[${fields[$2]}]}"
  else
    printf -v ProfSeq 'Invalid input! Your Header is: %s' "$1"
  fi
}

$ ParseHeader "XXXXX|Y|1|20220429|9999" "seq"
$ echo "$ProfSeq"
Sequence: 1
$ ParseHeader "XXXXX|Y|1|20220429|9999" "date"
$ echo "$ProfSeq"
Sequence: 20220429
$ ParseHeader "XXXXX|Y|1|20220429|9999" "count"
$ echo "$ProfSeq"
Line Count: 9999
$ ParseHeader "XXXXX|Y|1|20220429|9999" "foo"
$ echo "$ProfSeq"
Invalid input! Your Header is: 31
```